# DevExpress MVC GridView - SetDropDownWindowTemplateContent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

I'm working on a DevExpress gridview and finding a severe lack in documentation for a function call. Everywhere I look, SetDropDownWindowTemplateContent(string content) has no exmaples of what string content is or looks like. I've tried simply doing "Option1;Option2 (as devexpress states ';' is the delimiter) but it doesnt work.

Please help, pulling my hair out.

```
settings.Columns.Add(col =>
{
    col.FieldName = "DefaultValue";
    col.Caption = "Rule Type Value";
    col.Width = 300;
    col.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.DropDownEdit;
    col.SetEditItemTemplateContent(column =>
    {
        Html.DevExpress().DropDownEdit(c =>
        {
            c.Name = "ddlName";
            c.SetDropDownWindowTemplateContent("WHAT GOES HERE!?!?!");
        }).Render();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you contact the DX guys regarding your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](http://demos.devexpress.com/MVC/Editors/DropDownEdit) demo to learn more on how to use this method.

```
settings.SetDropDownWindowTemplateContent(c => {
    Html.DevExpress().ListBox(
        listBoxSettings => {
            ...
        }
    ).Render();
});
```